# Square bracket ([) inside a macro causes error

Tags: macros, errors, arguments

I have a program that scrapes many articles from a particular website, I convert the article from HTML to LaTeX with lots of if and elses, but now I can't rescrape them since I've already downloaded 1555+ issues and converted them into tex and it will take alot of time to pull it again and i don't want to put more burden on the server. Now my problem is that some of the article generates a cumbersome form of text, (`\tboxsup{\textbf{[Picture on page 16}, \textbf{17]}}`) and that causes the LaTeX to complain. In short, how do I escape the brackets to solve my problem?

[here is how vim notifies me of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qENH.png)

I can't really simply wrap **manually** them with `{}` because it occurs in random articles. I am planning to use `sed` to fix them.

---

**mwe**

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newcommand{\tboxsup}[1]{
\begin{center}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,
     breakable,
     width=0.75\textwidth,
     colback=white,
     colframe=darkgray,
     colupper=darkgray,
     boxrule=-1pt,
     arc=0pt,
     boxsep=3pt,
     colbacktitle=darkgray,
          title=#1]

}

\begin{document}
\tboxsup{\textbf{[Picture on page 12}, \textbf{13]}}

Egyptian model depicting the preparation of bread and beer
\vspace{.5em}

\textbf{[Credit Line]}
\vspace{.5em}

Su concessione del Ministero per i Beni e le Attività Culturali-Museo Egizio-Torino
\vspace{.5em}

\end{tcolorbox}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: The square bracket does not cause the error, the missing `}`causes it: `\textbf{{[Picture on page 16}}, \textbf{17]}`

Comment: I must have mistyped it. Here is the syntax highlight of vim https://imgur.com/a/jlJxXSK

Comment: Please make a [mre] instead of code fragments we would need to puzzle together

Comment: I apologize! I've added it now. I hope to know how I can escape those independent square brackets

Comment: @JulianoDavidHilario : Why is this question tagged with _shell_ and _linux_. It is not related to either.

Comment: Shouldn't `tboxsup` be an environment? `\newenvironment{tboxsup}[1]{<current code for \tboxsup>}{\end{tcolorbox}\end{center}}` (use `title={#1}` as suggested), so you don't have lonely `\end{tcolorbox}` and `\end{center}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you try to use a square bracket inside an optional argument. You can hide them by wrapping `#1` in an additional group of `{}`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newcommand{\tboxsup}[1]{
\begin{center}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,
     breakable,
     width=0.75\textwidth,
     colback=white,
     colframe=darkgray,
     colupper=darkgray,
     boxrule=-1pt,
     arc=0pt,
     boxsep=3pt,
     colbacktitle=darkgray,
          title={#1}]

}

\begin{document}
\tboxsup{\textbf{[Picture on page 12}, \textbf{13]}}

Egyptian model depicting the preparation of bread and beer
\vspace{.5em}

\textbf{[Credit Line]}
\vspace{.5em}

Su concessione del Ministero per i Beni e le Attività Culturali-Museo Egizio-Torino
\vspace{.5em}

\end{tcolorbox}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!!! I didn't have to do some ```sed```ing after all since it is all in the preamble